# Using the Euler-Lagrange equation to evaluate an integral

Tags: calculus-of-variations

I think this is a very basic question. I'm just not sure how to use $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}\right)=\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$ to find the general solution to:
$$\int \left(y^2 − y'^{\\2}- 2y \cos( 2x)\right) \:\mathrm{d}x$$

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply apply the equation $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} - \frac{d}{dx}(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}) = 0$$ for $F(x , y , y') = y^2 - y'^2 - 2y\cos(2x)$, you shall get $y'' - y = \cos(2x)$ (Please check the calculation).

Hope you can solve the second order ODE.

Comment: Ahh so it's just a simple matter of applying and solving. Does this solve for a stationary solution of y? And i got $y''+y=\cos(2x)$?

Comment: I do not see anything more than except solving the ODE

Comment: This is just more of a general question, not specifically related to this question. The solution we get from the Euler Lagrange equation has stationary value for the integral? According to Wolfram at least; http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-LagrangeDifferentialEquation.html

Comment: Any chance for assistance here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1066495/minimization-of-variational-total-variation-tv-deblurring